# Chrome opens for a second and the crashes

Tags: c#, appium, selenium-chromedriver

I'm using Appium and C# in order to run tests on my Galaxy S5. 
Everyhting worked perfectly , but last night we have updated the ChromeDriver to 2.25 and suddenly the chrome in my **mobile** just open the chrome, shows "data:" in the URL and crashes. on the other hand, the chrome in on Windows OS(selenium) works well.

```js
  [SetUp]
        public void Setup() 
       {
           DesiredCapabilities capabilities = new DesiredCapabilities();
           capabilities.SetCapability("device", "Android");
           capabilities.SetCapability("deviceName", "Galaxy S5");
           capabilities.SetCapability("newCommandTimeout", "300");
           capabilities.SetCapability("platformName", "Android");
           capabilities.SetCapability("platformVersion", "6.0.1");
           capabilities.SetCapability("appPackage", "com.android.chrome");
           capabilities.SetCapability("appActivity", "org.chromium.chrome.browser.ChromeTabbedActivity");
         _driver = new AndroidDriver<AppiumWebElement>(new Uri("http://127.0.0.1:4723/wd/hub"), capabilities, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(180));

        
        }
```

Appium's ERROR:

```html
 info: [debug] Responding to client with error: {"status":33,"value":{"message":"A new session could not be created. (Original error: A new session could not be created. (Original error: session not created exception\nfrom unknown error: Runtime.executionContextCreated has invalid 'context': {\"auxData\":{\"frameId\":\"31754.1\",\"isDefault\":true},\"id\":1,\"name\":\"\",\"origin\":\"://\"}\n  (Session info: chrome=54.0.2840.85)\n  (Driver info: chromedriver=2.18.343845 (73dd713ba7fbfb73cbb514e62641d8c96a94682a),platform=Windows NT 6.1 SP1 x86_64)))","status":33,"value":
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

updating the Appium's chromedriver manually to the latest one fixed the problem for me.

just downlaod the latest chromedriver vsersion and put it in the following path:

C:\Program Files (x86)\Appium\node_modules\appium\node_modules\appium-chromedriver\chromedriver\win

Comment: If you solved it then please mark your answer as the answer for the question.

Comment: I will. Within 19 hours