# "Error: no such session" Webdriver-IO, Appium

Tags: appium, webdriver-io

I have setup Cucumber, Webdriver-IO, and Appium. Everything appears to be talking to each other, however I'm getting `Error: no such session` when trying to navigate to `http://google.com`.

On the Android device it opens up the Chrome browser, then closes it really fast.

**webdriverio.js**

```
//webdriverio.js
let client = WebDriverIO.remote({
    desiredCapabilities: {
        platformName: 'Android',                        
      browserName: 'chrome',                          
      deviceName: 'test',
    },
    host: 'localhost',                                  
    port: 4723,                                     
    waitForTimeout: 120 * 1000,
});

global.client = client;

module.exports = function() {
  this.registerHandler('BeforeFeatures', function(event, done) {
    client.init().call(done);
  });

  this.registerHandler('AfterFeatures', function(event, done) {
    client.end().call(done);
  });
};
```

**env.js**

```
// env.js
module.exports = function() {
  // added because default 50000 ms was long enough
  this.setDefaultTimeout(60 * 1000);
};
```

**search_steps.js**

```
// search_steps.js
module.exports = function() {
  this.Given('I have visited Google', function (done) {
    client
      .url('http://google.com')
      .call(done);
  });

    this.When('I search for {arg1:stringInDoubleQuotes}', function (arg1, done) {
     // Write code here that turns the phrase above into concrete actions
     client
        .setValue('input[name="q"]', 'Kittens')
        .call(done);
    });


    this.Then('I see {arg1:stringInDoubleQuotes}', function (arg1, done) {
         // Write code here that turns the phrase above into concrete actions
         client
            .getValue('input[name="q"]').then(function(text){
                expect('Kittens').to.eql(text);
            })
            .call(done);
    });


};
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is chromedriver 2.21.371459 that is shipped with my version of Appium (1.3.5) for Mac. I downloaded the latest version of chromedriver and overwritten the existing one that is shipped with Appium. See the answer here [Chrome opens for a second and the crashes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40701588/chrome-opens-for-a-second-and-the-crashes/40702234#40702234) for windows. For mac the location of the chromedriver exec  shipped with Appium is. /Applications/Appium.app/Contents/Resources/node_modules/appium/node_modules/appium-android-driver/node_modules/appium-chromedriver/chromedriver/mac